# How to disclose source of a software with Mozilla Public Licence?

Tags: licensing, mpl

How can I disclose the source of a software with Mozilla Public License?
Do I have to give a link to the source code from the software?

Is there any problem to give the source of original repository (my software is copied) instead of modified version (changes made by me)?

Comment: "respiratory"??? I guess you mean "repository", don't you?

Answer (score 1):

The  [Mozilla FAQ page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/FAQ/) on MPL licensed code makes clear in Q9 and Q10 that if you distribute software containing MPL licensed code, you must make available the source of the MPL licensed portion of code "*including any Modifications that you have created*".

So it's not ok to give the source of the original code instead of your modified version.

***Disclaimer:*** this is a personal opinion and not legal advice.  For legal advice, please consult a lawyer or a qualified legal expert in your jurisdiction